# Blocking Queue - Why is there no notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, producer-consumer

I was going through this bounding queue code online trying to understand it

```
public class BlockingQueue {

  private List queue = new LinkedList();
  private int  limit = 10;

  public BlockingQueue(int limit){
    this.limit = limit;
  }


  public synchronized void enqueue(Object item)
  throws InterruptedException  {
    while(this.queue.size() == this.limit) {
      wait();
    }
    if(this.queue.size() == 0) {
      notifyAll();
    }
    this.queue.add(item);
  }


  public synchronized Object dequeue()
  throws InterruptedException{
    while(this.queue.size() == 0){
      wait();
    }
    if(this.queue.size() == this.limit){
      notifyAll();
    }

    return this.queue.remove(0);
  }

}
```

My understanding is this:

1. if there are no more items in the queue, nothing can be dequeued and so we call a wait()
2. if there are maximum number of items in the queue, nothing can be enqueued and so we call a wait()
3. if there is some space (and some elements) in the queue we can call enqueue as well as dequeue
4. also we notifyAll() so that all producers and consumers wake up

But what happens to the requests that we call wait() on. Do they only get notified on the notifyAll() call? Why do they not get notified as soon as their is space in the queue?

Comment: It's just that i can only see notifyAll() here but no notify. How do they get notified?

Comment: What do you think `notifyAll` does?

Comment: notifyAll() only gets called in enqueue when there are no more elements and in dequeue when there are max elements. My question is exactly that.

Why wait for those limits? Why not notify as soon as possible?

Comment: `notifyAll` also gets called on `dequeue` if the queue is at the size limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to notify when adding to an empty queue, because dequeuers are only waiting on an empty queue.

Similarly you only need to notify when dequeueing from a full queue, because enqueuers are only waiting on a full queue.

Comment: Oh, I guess it's starting to make sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two minutiae to notice for understanding the code:

1. Threads also have to acquire lock before waking, which is why the two `notifyAll` can be placed at a place other than the last line.
2. In addition to waiting, there is also queuing. When no thread is waiting on its condition, all of them are queuing up to get the lock, and this is the reason the code only does `notifyAll` when the queue reaches full or empty.